# Filter within GroupBy objects in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Here's a sample dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3], 
                   'value':[42, 89, 250, 31, 130, 108, 107, 93]})

    ID  value
0    1     42
1    1     89
2    1    250
3    2     31
4    2    130
5    2    108
6    3    107
7    3     93
```

For each ID I want to extract the entries with values greater than 100.

Using `groupby` I can get the following

```
grouped = df.groupby('ID')
for name, group in grouped:
    print(name, group)

1    ID  value
0     1     42
1     1     89
2     1    250
2    ID  value
3     2     31
4     2    130
5     2    108
3    ID  value
6     3    107
7     3     93
```

I want to apply a condition to each group to get the following:

```
1    ID  value
2     1    250
2    ID  value
4     2    130
5     2    108
3    ID  value
6     3    107
```

I have tried using `groupby.filter` but that outputs a boolean condition for an entire group. I want to apply a boolean condition within a group. How can I do this?

EDIT: I should specify that the condition is different within each group, so I need to do groupby first.

Comment: Hmm, why do you need a groupby when you can apply the operation to the whole thing?

Comment: I edited the question to clarify that the condition is different for each group so a boolean filter on the whole dataframe won't work.

Comment: Do you determine what to select based on the keys? If so, there are better solutions. Maybe you could provide some explanation?

Comment: The limit is set by the distribution of values within each group. For example, select all values greater than the group mean.

Comment: Something like `df[df.value > df.groupby('ID')['value'].transform('mean')]`?

Comment: That works too thanks! I'll upvote it if you post it as an answer.

Comment: Ah, that's alright, thanks. That would make your question a duplicate anyway, so best not post it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) before or in loop:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3], 
                   'value':[42, 89, 250, 31, 130, 108, 10, 93]})

print (df)
   ID  value
0   1     42
1   1     89
2   1    250
3   2     31
4   2    130
5   2    108
6   3     10
7   3     93
```

If some group have no value matched is omitted like group `3`:

```
grouped = df[df['value'] > 100].groupby('ID')
for name, group in grouped:
    print(name, group)
1    ID  value
2   1    250
2    ID  value
4   2    130
5   2    108
```

Or if filter in loop is returned empty DataFrame for not matched group:

```
grouped = df.groupby('ID')
for name, group in grouped:
    print(name, group[group['value'] > 100])

1    ID  value
2   1    250
2    ID  value
4   2    130
5   2    108
3 Empty DataFrame
Columns: [ID, value]
Index: []
```

EDIT:

If want filter by values different for each group is possible solution with [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by dictionary with `ID` column, then compare with `value` and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
d = {1:100, 2: 121, 3: 10}

df = df[df['value'] > df['ID'].map(d)]
print (df)
   ID  value
2   1    250
4   2    130
7   3     93
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['ID'].map(d))
0    100
1    100
2    100
3    121
4    121
5    121
6     10
7     10
Name: ID, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks - I edited the question to clarify that the condition is different for each group so a boolean filter on the whole dataframe won't work.

Comment: I think your last example answers my question. If I use `group[group['value']] > x` and loop through different `x` values depending on the group I can get the behavior I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We can do grater than query this way in pandas ..

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3], 'value':[42, 89, 250, 31, 130, 108, 107,      93]})
df3 = df.query('value > 100')
print(df3.head())
```

Output will be

```
   ID  value
2   1    250
4   2    130
5   2    108
6   3    107
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a function:

```
def f(df, n):
    return df[df['value'] > n]

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3],
                   'value':[42, 89, 250, 31, 130, 108, 107, 93]})

res = df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: f(x, 100))
```